# Flash CS6/AS3.0 image scale to screen?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash

I have been working on some apps recently, and have made all of the images (home screens, buttons, etc) in Photoshop. I realize now that this probably wasn't the best idea, because the quality is terrible when I put it into Flash CS6.

I am now working in Illustrator to use vector instead, but I need to know how to make a bitmap image (for the welcome screen) display nicely, and scale to the screen. It will be running on Android and iOS devices, so there is no "universal" size I can think of.

The image's dimensions are 2195x2195

One last note... will vector artwork scale on it's own?

Comment: If you're capable of exporting your vector graphics into Flash CSx as "Graphics" objects (or "Shape"), then by all means use this. Still, you'll have to downscale your vector graphics by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> will vector artwork scale on it's own?

No, nothing in the AS3 project will scale on it's own, it's up to a programmer to decide how and when scale objects. But, vector will give you flexibility especially with great diversity of the screen sizes in Android. Your vector graphics will upscale/downscale without losing quality. While upscaling of Bitmap will give you poor quality, so as a developer you are forced to prepare graphics that will be downscaled. You have headache especially with Android, how big is your image should be, etc.

As for scaling objects, so they will fit predefined boundaries, and if you don't familiar with the Math, you could use helpful class from the GreenSock library - [AutoFitArea](http://www.greensock.com/autofitarea/)